# How to integrate/use `WKWebView` plugin in PhoneGap application

Tags: ios, cordova, uiwebview, phonegap-plugins, wkwebview

I have a Phonegap iOS application in which I am using Angular Kendo mobile framework for build UI.

I want to use `WKWebView` in my application instead of UIWebView.
So what all steps I need to follow to do so?

I tried to integrate it by adding the WKWebView plugin but in my application I see blank page only and in logs errors for loading html pages.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the plugin like this:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-wkwebview
```

And after that in your `config.xml` add this:

```
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview" />
    <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    </feature>

    <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried the first step as you have mentioned by installing the plugin but i have not did the config.xml related changes. I fee because of that I am not able to see any page in my app, will try this solution.

Comment: The feature tag has been deprecated as of March 7 2016 - http://phonegap.com/blog/2016/02/24/phonegap-build-confg-xml-now-required-and-other-updates/. How should we use the CDWKWebViewEngine within iOS app build with PhoneGap Build?

Comment: @LaurenceC It might work without specifying the `<feature>` tag at all in PhoneGap Build. Did you tried without `<feature>` ?

Comment: @DanielDudas I found out eventually that no matter what I did I couldn't get a PG Build iOS app to compile using cli 6.0.0 or above no matter what I did - I previously got an app building with cli-6.0.0 so I'm not sure what happened here.

Are you able to get the view engine working using only:

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview" />
<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />

in your config.xml file?

Comment: @LaurenceC I am not using Phonegap Build for iOS build, I create the build from xcode. Also I use an older version.  (5.2.0)